# Python Code for aggregating lines

Tags: python-3.x

Looking for python code that will convert the below lines

```
interface port-channel 1
ALLOWED_VLAN 2,4-7,27,30-31,38-39,41-42,48-50
ALLOWED_VLAN 74,678,1101-1102,1201-1202
interface port-channel 2
ALLOWED_VLAN 37,51-52,75-76,1051-1052,2001
interface port-channel 101
ALLOWED_VLAN 10,18-19,37,39,51-52,75-76,901-902
ALLOWED_VLAN 2901-2902,3204,3305
```

into

```
interface port-channel 1
ALLOWED_VLAN 2,4-7,27,30-31,38-39,41-42,48-50,74,678,1101-1102,1201-1202
interface port-channel 2
ALLOWED_VLAN 37,51-52,75-76,1051-1052,2001
interface port-channel 101
ALLOWED_VLAN 10,18-19,37,39,51-52,75-76,901-902,2901-2902,3204,3305
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the replace function. What you basically want to achieve is replacing the second "ALLOWED_VLAN" after each interface. 
You could also use find to get the first occurrence of the substring. After that you would start the search for find from there and get the index of the second "ALLOWED_VLAN". Then you could split the string in the parts before this substring and after the substring and concatenate those two parts.

As stack overflow is no we code for you site I only described the idea but not the whole python code.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, i will try that

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
lines = []

with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        lines.append(line.rstrip())

new_lines = []

i = 0 
while i < len(lines) - 1:
    line = lines[i]
    counter = 1
    while i + counter < len(lines):
        next_line = lines[i+counter]
        if line.split()[0] == next_line.split()[0]:
            line += "," + next_line.split()[-1]
            counter += 1
        else:
            break
    i += counter
    new_lines.append(line)

print(new_lines)
```

Result:

```
[
'interface port-channel 1', 
'ALLOWED_VLAN 2,4-7,27,30-31,38-39,41-42,48-50,74,678,1101-1102,1201-1202', 
'interface port-channel 2', 
'ALLOWED_VLAN 37,51-52,75-76,1051-1052,2001', 
'interface port-channel 101', 
'ALLOWED_VLAN 10,18-19,37,39,51-52,75-76,901-902,2901-2902,3204,3305,2901-2902,3204,3305' 
]
```

Basically, the algorithm iterates down the list greedily checking the next line to see if the first word is the same. If it's not it immediately breaks the inner while loop only incrementing `i` by `1`.

However, if there's a match, subsequent lines are consumed in the inner while loop until the if-statement breaks, and `i` is incremented by the number of consumed lines.

As such, while the loop is doubly nested, it still has a runtime of `O(n)`. However, it can use up to `O(2n)` space. To avoid this (if your list is huge), you can do the mutation in place (but this will increase the runtime):

```
lines_to_remove = []

i = 0 
while i < len(lines) - 1:
    line = lines[i]
    counter = 1
    while i+counter < len(lines):
        next_line = lines[i+counter]
        if line.split()[0] == next_line.split()[0]:
            lines[i] += "," + next_line.split()[-1]
            lines_to_remove.append(i + counter)
            counter += 1
        else:
            break
    i += counter

for index in sorted(lines_to_remove, reverse=True):
    del lines[index]

print(lines)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the issue i have is i am reading it from txt file

Comment: That's not an issue - I just didn't include it for brevity. Would you prefer to read in the file and get a list in python, or output to another file? I've updated the example to include the first case - but can add file output if you prefer aswell.

Comment: Thanks Man, i am new to programming, would like yo learn more, are u a programmer, i would like to have u as my mentor